# SQL table data export to txt file on desktop

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Hey guys I need some help exporting a SQL table using WPF application in C#. I need it to run as soon as the application starts. Heres example code:

```
public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        testie();
    }
```

This is the main window I am trying to initialize at the start of the program.
Here is my method:

```
private void testie(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=sqlserver;" + "Initial Catalog=database;" + "Integrated Security=True;";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                // handle
                return;
            }
            string selectCommandText = "SELECT * FROM tablet";
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommandText, connection))
            {
                using (DataTable table = new DataTable("tablet"))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(table);
                    StringBuilder commaDelimitedText = new StringBuilder();
                    //   commaDelimitedText.AppendLine("col1,col2,col3"); // optional if you want column names in first row
                    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                    {
                        string value = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", row[0], row[1], row[2]); // how you format is up to you (spaces, tabs, delimiter, etc)
                        commaDelimitedText.AppendLine(value);
                    }
                    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\desktop\test666.txt", commaDelimitedText.ToString());




                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I get an error "No overload for method 'testie' takes 0 arguments."
If I change the method from:

```
private void testie(string[] args)
```

to:

```
private void testie(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I run into the same problem.
Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void testie()
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: This did it, wow do I feel silly. Question, using the code above with your suggestion, I need it to bool any suggestion on how I could add a bool?
Basically, need it to run, update the same text file as the data changes regularly.